# jobschedulerのメール送信設定について

Tags: aws, sendmail

### 発生している問題

AWS上にjobschedulerをインストールして利用しようとしているのですが、ジョブの終了時にメールが送信されずにいます。
/var/log/maillog を見ても送信されたログが無いので、jobschedulerの設定がおかしいと考えています。

現在、以下のサイトのオーダ（3つのジョブを実行するジョブチェーン）が登録されているので、まずはこのオーダが終了した時に、成功・失敗をメールで通知させたいと考えています。
http://tech-sketch.jp/2014/04/%E3%82%AA%E3%83%BC%E3%83%97%E3%83%B3%E3%82%BD%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B9%E3%81%AA%E3%82%B8%E3%83%A7%E3%83%96%E7%AE%A1%E7%90%86%E3%83%84%E3%83%BC%E3%83%AB-sos-jobscheduler-%E3%82%92%E4%BD%BF%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6-3.html

もしお分かりの方がいらっしゃいましたら、jobschedulerのメール送信設定をご教授いただけないでしょうか。

---

### 補足情報 (OS, ツールのバージョンなど)

#### ■ 環境

- Amazon Linux
- jobscheduler.1.9.2
- openjdk version "1.8.0_45"

※ec2-userがsendmailコマンドでメール送信できるように設定を変更済み

#### ■ メール送信の設定（メールアドレスは※で伏せています）

```sh
/home/ec2-user/jobscheduler/scheduler/config/factory.ini
～略～
[spooler]
;                         directory of the OperationsGUI
html_dir                = ${SCHEDULER_HOME}/operations_gui

;                         send mail with job log in case of error (yes|no, default: no)
mail_on_error           = yes
;                         send mail with job log in case of errors and warnings (yes|no, default: no)
mail_on_warning         = yes
;                         send mail with job log in case of success (yes|no, default: no)
mail_on_success         = yes
;                         send mail with job log in case of process steps (yes|no|1|2|n, default: no)
mail_on_process         = no

;                         sender and recipients for mails with job logs
log_mail_from           = ※@gmail.com
log_mail_to             = ※@gmail.com
log_mail_cc             = ※@gmail.com
log_mail_bcc            =

;                         mail server hostname
smtp                    = localhost
;                         directory in which mails are stored if your mail server is not available
mail_queue_dir          = ${SCHEDULER_DATA}/mail
～略～
[smtp]
mail.smtp.user          =

mail.smtp.password      =

mail.smtp.port          = 25
～略～
```